# 404 Image Nominations

Tags: discussion, beta-essentials

According to the [Top 7](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), we need to select a 404 image - an image that will be displayed when users try to bring up a page that does not exist.

Please quote the source so the team can negotiate rights if necessary.

<sub>* this post is a verbatim copy of the one on meta.unix.stackexchange.com... I'm not particularly creative but we should start thinking about this: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/404-image-nominations</sub>

Answer (score 10):

We could use the image that a Mac uses when it can't find the startup drive:

[image]

It's a little small, but we could scale it/pad it with gray.

Comment: I'm sure Jin could riff on that theme and come up with something appropriate that would work with the site's style.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my shot at it:

[image]

Yanked from http://macamour.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/macosx_kernel_panic.png

Comment: Nice, this definitely should be one of the images used, though this might work better as a 503 than a 404.

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: ya you're right, it would be perfect for a 503 (which hopefully won't happen very often).

Comment: The problem is that some “less computer savvy” users might actually restart their computer… ;)

Comment: Yeah, what Martín said. The image and style (translated text) would be great. But the actual text needs to be changed...

Comment: Clever, but for any usage I think we would need all of the non-English languages translated. Google Translate doesn't count.

Comment: I can have it perfectly translated to Spanish, Italian and German. I have a french friend who would be able to do the French part. Good luck with the… japanese?

Comment: Why translate it?  It's the way the kernel panic screen looks and is a huge part of the gag.  It doesn't have to have every language in the workd on it, that's not the way the real one looks.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: APIEpicFail is amazing :) I had seen that sshot once.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think a picture of bill gates 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Bill_Gates_in_WEF_%2C2007.jpg
Or a windows logo will be good. 
That or one of those Windows error messages that says something like "error: process completed successfully".

(yes I do realise this is apple.SE but apple things *never* go wrong ;) )

EDIT: or something similar to this picture http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/win-eating-apple.jpg or in reverse.

Comment: That's actually kind of funny since the SE servers are Windows based I think :)