# Our 404 Page is Boring

Tags: discussion, status-completed, style

I stumbled onto a question that was deleted before I refreshed the page (read: could answer the question) and I noticed that we have an awfully boring 404 page. I feel that this is a grave problem!

This post may be a bit unnecessary, considering that we have the [404 Image Nominations](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/404-image-nominations) question, but here it is anyways.

I've moved my suggestions into an answer, to clean up the question a little bit. Splitting the facts from the opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated the 404 image with the sad Mac one. It will be in the next deployment.

Comment: meh.. I liked the *drive not found* better, but.. I'm not really a user of this site hehehe  :P  :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm very partial to both of the initial suggestions in the 2 top rated answers;

[image: Sad Mac]

and

[image: Boot Drive Not Found]

I will say that if we used Sad Mac, I would love to change the text to be 404 in hex values. But the OS Drive Not Found error needs no other labels, IMO.

This is all certainly much better than a generic frowny face that we currently have.